# Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

On onclick I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: akkiTooltip is not defined`.
Check the code that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function akkiTooltip() {
        function applyTooltip(element, word) {
            var tooltipText = $('' + element + ' label').data('tooltip');
            var newContent = $('' + element + ' label').html().replace(word, '<span data-tooltip="' + tooltipText + '">' + word + '</span>');
            $('' + element + ' label').removeAttr('data-tooltip');
            return $('' + element + ' label').html(newContent);
        }
        applyTooltip('#question_307', 'Some text');
    }
});
```

This is from another js file where I am applying onclick:

```
$(button)
    .text(this.answers[a].title)
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .attr('class', 'btn')
    .attr('onclick', 'quiz._makeSelection(\'answer_' + this.answers[a].id + '\', ' + go + ', ' + this.answers[a].skipToSection + '); akkiTooltip();');
```

---

After moving `akkiTooltip` function outside `$(document).ready` function, I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Move definition of `akkitooltip` function outside `document.ready` function. It is not accessible from there.

Comment: Just did it, now got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: Also you are passing the same values to applytooltip function. If there is no element on page with id as 'question_307' you will get an error.

Comment: Nope, there is a element with id question_307.

Comment: Is there a label inside it?

Comment: Yes there is a label inside.

Answer (score 0):

> `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

See where you are using `.replace`

```
$('' + element + ' label').html().replace(word, '...');
```

So, `$('' + element + ' label').html()` is not what you expect, i.e. `$('' + element + ' label')` found no elements so `.html()` did not return a *String*

Check an element described by the selector `#question_307 label` exists

---

*When I tried reproducing this error I actually got `null` instead of `undefined` so it might be a different piece of your code*

Comment: No, I am getting undefined, I just checked tooltipText on console, I got undefined.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check if you set  right:

1.In html and jsp webpage:

```
<script src=""></script>
```

2.In xhtml webpage:

```
<script src="" />
```

3.and if your js code(function code) is in the same webpage with the html, you can just use:

```
<script> {your js code} </script>
```

the default script type is "test/javascript"